# Using sankey-diagram in grafana with mysql-source

Tags: mysql, grafana, sankey-diagram

I am trying to create sankey-diagrams within grafana, using:
https://github.com/kumaravel29/grafana-sankey-panel

I have problems understanding how to create a sankey diagram with multiple "layers".
With the following statement, I can create a diagram with one input (metric) and the associated output

```
select sum(a) as "a", sum(b) as "b", sum(c) as metric
from foo
group by "a", "b"
```

Now I would like to add another layer, e.g. first layer -> metric, second layer -> a,b, third layer -> another calculation. With regard to the documentation, I have no idea how to realize this. Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I would love to find some example datasets for this plugin.

Comment: Hi kodybrown, no, unfortunately I never got the plugin working for the task, but I switched to thus plugin:
https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/netsage-sankey-panel/